# Herança com construtores

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, herança, construtor

Preciso criar uma classe base `animal` e 3 outras classes hereditárias de outros animais. Cada classe deverá ter sua própria função `emitirSom`. Elas devem ser invocadas de forma polimórfica através de um vector. Acontece que eu não sei se o construtor foi feito certo. Tipo, o construtor deve ser feito na classe base ou nas classes hereditárias?

[image: Tela de erro]

Mensagens de erro:

> main.cpp(15): error C2661: 'cachorro::cachorro': nenhuma função sobrecarregada recebe 2 argumentos
>
> main.cpp(16): error C2661: 'vaca::vaca': nenhuma função sobrecarregada recebe 2 argumentos
>
> main.cpp(17): error C2661: 'gato::gato': nenhuma função sobrecarregada recebe 2 argumentos

Header.h

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class animal
{
protected:
    string nome;
    int idade;
public:
    animal(const string &nome_, int idade_);
    virtual void emitirSom() const = 0;
};

class cachorro : public animal
{
public:
    virtual void emitirSom() const;
};

class vaca : public animal
{
    virtual void emitirSom() const;
};

class gato: public animal
{
    virtual void emitirSom() const;
};
```

Implmentation.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

animal::animal(const string &nome_, int idade_)
{
    nome = nome_;
    idade = -idade_;
}
void cachorro::emitirSom() const
{
    cout << "\n" << nome << "latindo: Aauauauauau";
}

void gato::emitirSom() const
{
    cout << "\n" << nome << "miando: MiauMiau";
}

void vaca::emitirSom() const
{
    cout << "\n" << nome << "mugindo: Muuuuuuu";
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "header.h"
#include <vector>

void fazerBarulho(const animal* const &bicho)
{
    bicho->emitirSom();
}

int main()
{
    cachorro toby("Toby", 8);
    vaca lili("Lili",29);
    gato satanas("Satanas",3);

    vector < animal * > zoo( 3 );

    zoo[0] = &toby;
    zoo[1] = &lili;
    zoo[2] = &satanas;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < zoo.size(); ++i)
        fazerBarulho(zoo[0]);
#if WIN32
    system("PAUSE");
#endif
}
```

Comment: A imagem tem algum propósito? Ela fica horrivelmente renderizados junto à pergunta na versão mobile do site

Comment: É a tela de erro. Pera que eu vou copiar o texto

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/64969

Comment: agora lendo a mensagem de erro consegui entender sua dúvida, +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa criar os construtores das classes derivas e chamar o construtor da classe base. Tem uma sintaxe própria para isto. Tinham mais alguns erros que eu corrigi.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class animal
{
protected:
    string nome;
    int idade;
public:
    animal(const string &nome_, int idade_);
    virtual void emitirSom() const = 0;
};

class cachorro : public animal
{
public:
    cachorro(const string &nome_, int idade_);
    virtual void emitirSom() const;
};

class vaca : public animal
{
public:
    vaca(const string &nome_, int idade_);
    virtual void emitirSom() const;
};

class gato: public animal
{
public:
    gato(const string &nome_, int idade_);
    virtual void emitirSom() const;
};

animal::animal(const string &nome_, int idade_)
{
    nome = nome_;
    idade = -idade_;
}

cachorro::cachorro(const string &nome_, int idade_) : animal(nome_, idade_) {}

void cachorro::emitirSom() const
{
    cout << "\n" << nome << "latindo: Aauauauauau";
}

gato::gato(const string &nome_, int idade_) : animal(nome_, idade_) {}

void gato::emitirSom() const
{
    cout << "\n" << nome << "miando: MiauMiau";
}

vaca::vaca(const string &nome_, int idade_) : animal(nome_, idade_) {}

void vaca::emitirSom() const
{
    cout << "\n" << nome << "mugindo: Muuuuuuu";
}

void fazerBarulho(const animal* const &bicho)
{
    bicho->emitirSom();
}

int main()
{
    cachorro toby("Toby", 8);
    vaca lili("Lili",29);
    gato satanas("Satanas",3);

    vector < animal * > zoo( 3 );

    zoo[0] = &toby;
    zoo[1] = &lili;
    zoo[2] = &satanas;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < zoo.size(); ++i)
        fazerBarulho(zoo[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/cCyF4D). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hmxhdegu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/OOP/ConstructorInheritance.cpp).