# Classes com herança e método set

Tags: herança, uml

Estou com uma duvida, estou desenvolvendo uma modelagem simples com uma superclasse pessoa e duas outras subclasses pessoa física e pessoa jurídica.

Estou confuso em relação ao metodo SET. Não sei se devo passar os valores dos atributos por parâmetro no momento da chamada do metodo SET, já que se trata de muitos parâmetros.. Preciso de alguma sujestão ou recomendação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que é este `set` ele parece bem esquisito. O `get` também um pouco, pode explicar melhor, principalmente o que retornam.

Comment: o método set é para cadastrar o nome, endereço, etc... o get vai retornar os valores.

Comment: @CleristonMartinsCardoso esse não deveria ser o construtor? Os métodos get/set costumam estarem relacionados a apenas um campo da classe.

Comment: Isso não faz sentido.

Comment: Em vez do set, use o construtor da classe passando os parâmetros. Outra opção é você dar uma pesquisada sobre um _design pattern_ chamado `Builder`, que serve para casos em que seu objeto tem muitos campos. [Aqui](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternBuilder/article.html) tem um exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado a todos, vou seguir a recomendação do construtor e vou ler sobre o design pattern Builder.

Comment: @CleristonMartinsCardoso Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

`Pessoa` é abstrata? Deveria.

Parece estar precisando de construtor. Aí a superclasse tem um e as subclasses tem os seus próprios que recebem os dados necessário para ela e a superclasse.

O `set` não deveria ser usado para isto. O `get` não parece que deveria ser usado para isto.

Até há questionamentos se deveria usar esse tipo de artifício, mesmo fazendo certo.

Veja [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Em alguns casos essa pode não ser a solução, mas geralmente é. Veja mais em [Como e quando construir um objeto em estado válido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252765/101). Também pode ser útil: [Pode-se fazer override em construtores?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128233/101). E um [exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240500/101).

Eu não faria o que o Dherik faria, já que isso é *abstraction obssession*, o oposto do *primitive obssession* que certamente ele dirá que é o que faço. Costumo ser pragmático e usar o que precisa, o que me traz vantagem. Para este caso não vejo vantagem alguma e não simplifica nada, dependendo da linguagem eu até faria mais, por isso UML é quase um câncer, ela não considera se a implementação tem mais facilidades ou se beneficia do seu modelo. Em outro caso talvez até usasse. Claro, o `Endereco` provavelmente eu faria, conforme eu [respondi na outra pergunta do AP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/311979/101) (que já melhorou muito), mas não necessariamente.

Em UML é difícil mostrar exatamente a melhor forma porque é algo abstrato, a cultura e mecanismos de cada linguagem faz mudar a forma. E é um erro quando a pessoa não percebe isto. Para o bem as pessoas estão abandonando UML, eu nunca achei isso bom, não compro modismos sem embasamento prático.

Answer (score 0):

Não recomendaria o `set` e sim o uso de construtores no seu caso.

Em OOP, normalmente fica mais claro usar classes pequenas e iniciar os objetos por meio de seus construtores. Usar `set` para todos os campos deixa o objeto aberto a qualquer tipo de alteração de valores a qualquer momento, o que não é normalmente o desejado.

Começando com `Juridica`, ela poderia ter os seguintes campos em seu construtor:

```
nome, endereco, bairro, cep, cidade, estado, cnpj, tipo
```

E `Fisica`:

```
nome, endereco, bairro, cep, cidade, estado, rg, cpf
```

Porém, podemos melhorar isto, pois ainda temos **muitos parâmetros** ao invés de muitos métodos `set`. Como disse anteriormente, usar objetos menores, com maior significado, facilita o entendimento.

Sendo assim, eu criaria mais 4 classes: `Endereco`, `Cpf`, `Rg`, e `Cnpj`. Cada um com os seguintes campos em seus construtores:

- Endereco: `endereco, bairro, cep, cidade, estado`
- Cpf: `numero`
- Rg: `numero`
- Cnpj: `numero, tipo`

Veja que agora você tem uma representação mais organizada das informações que `Fisica` e `Juridica` recebem.

Assim, a classe `Juridica` receberia em seu construtor:

```
nome, Endereco, Cnpj
```

E no `Fisica`:

```
nome, Endereco, Cpf, Rg
```

Comment: Maravilha, e em relação ao get? Não sei se seria recomendavel eu ter vários metodos para pegar os valores dos atributos.. Por exemplo, getNome, getEndereco, getCpf..

Comment: O método `get` você cria apenas para as informações que você deseja obter depois. Ou seja, informações que o objeto pode fornecer para outros objetos. Pode fazer sentido para alguns campos, mas não para outros. No seu caso, parece fazer sentido para todos, não vejo problema algum.

Comment: Obrigado @Dherik