# Classes com associações em UML

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, classes, modelagem, uml

Sou da época da programação estruturada e agora estou retornando e tentando me adequar com a OOP. Fiz um diagrama abaixo. Estou no caminho certo?

Criei essa classe `Empresa` pensando em não ter que ficar limitado nas duas classes `PessoaJuridica` e `PessoaFfisica`.

[image: Diagrama de classes]

Comment: Faz sentido existir uma Pessoa sem CPF ou CNPJ? Se não, a classe Pessoa deveria ser abstrata. E o que seria Empresa? Por quê ela herda das duas pessoas? Se ela é ambas, nem faria sentido existir 4 classes; concentrar tudo em Pessoa ficaria muito mais simples. Faltou o campo Contatos em Pessoa para fazer a associação.

Comment: E eu não colocaria CEP, CNPJ, RG e CPF como inteiros. Eles são *strings* compostas apenas por caracteres numéricos, mas não valores numéricos.

Comment: Eu colocaria pelo menos os dois últimos como classes, pois são dados que possuem comportamento associado (a saber, a validação desses dados). Por exemplo, CPF tem uma validação dos dois últimos dígitos por módulo-11. Pode-se argumentar que endereço poderia ser uma entidade (classe) separada, mas não tenho experiência na implementação desse tipo de cenário para justificar. Não faz sentido nenhum que Empresa herde de uma Pessoa Física. Fale o que realmente deseja fazer para o pessoal dar sugestões de como pode ser feito.

Comment: @Cleriston, está no caminho certo sim, melhorou bastante desde sua última pergunta. Os questionamentos do pessoal são interessantes com relação aos tipos de dados usados, podemos nos aprofundar mais nisto agora. Chegando em casa posso te responder com mais calma. O que seria o `tipo`? Acho que cabe separar as informações de endereço em uma classe `Endereco`. Também é bom usar os construtores das classes, fica mais claro instanciar elas e saber suas dependências.

Comment: Obrigado Vou tentar explicar melhor o cenário que tenho em mente. Eu vou ter um cliente que pode ser pessoa física ou jurídica, o "tipo" representa outra característica específica da situação, por exemplo, o cliente pode ser um "Pedreiro" ou um "Pintor", A minha ideia em relação a classe empresa é para  eu ter apenas o objeto cliente(Empresa) e não diferenciar entre juridica e fisica. Se você tiver outra sugestão eu agradeço. Já a classe contato representa que todo cliente pode ter 0 ou vários contatos como email ou telefone.

Comment: @CleristonMartinsCardoso, entendi. Este `Empresa` ficou um pouco estranho, pois uma PF **pode ter** empresa e PJ **pode ser** uma empresa. Se me permite dizer até, não trabalharia com tantas heranças e sim com composição, mas pelo que entendi do seu contexto algumas pessoas esperam que você use herança, então vou tentar ajudar você neste linha de pensamento.

Comment: @Dherik eu lhe agradeço pela ajuda. O que vc acha de ter uma empresa com pessoa fisica e juridica como composição?

Comment: @CleristonMartinsCardoso, desde que PF e PJ tenham uma empresa (e não o contrário), sim.

Comment: Desculpem, eu fui meio curto e grosso em meu comentário. E nem tenho tanta experiência assim, fica aqui o meu pedido de desculpas. Espero também aprender com esse exemplo que estamos discutindo aqui. Posso perguntar qual o escopo do projeto? (se é um cadastro de clientes, com a profissão de cada um, ou algum outro contexto?)

Comment: Em outras palavras, qual o domínio da aplicação?

Comment: @Piovezan, Vou ter um cadastro de empresas clientes e parceiras, essas empresas podem ser pessoa fisica e juridica, cada uma vai ter a características específica são despachantes ou armadores.. Essas empresas vão ser clientes ou fornecedores de propostas comerciais que entraram em outro escopo. Futuramente, pretendo implementar um cadastro de vendedores e funcionários.

Comment: Nome deveria estar em Pessoa ou [nas classes-filhas](http://videos.web-03.net/artigos/Robson_Fernandes/ConceitoHerancaComposicao/ConceitoHerancaComposicao1.jpg)? Armador e despachante são [isso](https://cursosnocd.com.br/logistica/empresas-intervenientes-na-navegacao.htm)? Quais outras "pessoas" estão envolvidas? Como inseri-las no modelo? A modelagem não deveria ser primeiro conceitual e só depois no diagrama de classe? Não deveria partir de casos de uso? Agora entendo por que [é ampla](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7136/como-encaixar-perguntas-sobre-modelagem).

Comment: Para escolher a modelagem de papéis (sugiro o padrão 4): [http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2002_09/column2/](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2002_09/column2/)

Comment: @CleristonMartinsCardoso A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

Como assim da época da programação estruturada? Mudou alguma coisa que eu não sei? Eu ainda faço programação estruturada. Talvez esteja um pouco confuso com relação aos paradigmas. Uma coisa não elimina a outra. Inclusive eu evitaria assumir novos paradigmas sem entender esse fundamento e entender porque está adotando um paradigma novo no seu projeto. Fazer porque está na moda não é um bom motivo.

Tinha algum problema e agora fazendo OOP o resolve? Se não, não tem porque mudar. Fazia errado no procedural? Vai fazer OO certo? É mais difícil fazer certo orientado a objeto.

Não sou dos mais fãs de *getters/setters*. E tem linguagem que isso faz pouco sentido, um dos motivos que já nem gosto de UML (e muita gente está vendo que era pra não gostar mesmo). E tem <strike>ideo</strike>metodologia que prega que não deve usar. Mesmo OOP diz isso na sua forma mais pura, ainda que eu sempre ache um exagero.

O modelo parece estar acima da média. Mas é o que eu sempre digo, não sei qual é o problema, não posso dizer se é a solução certa.

`Pessoa` é abstrata? Deveria. O diagrama não mostra isso.

Ainda não está usando o construtor da maneira correta, parece não ter lido os *links* que passei na [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/311598/101).

Não sei se `Contato` deveria ser desta forma, mas estou especulando em um problema que não conheço. Pode ser que seja a solução exata. Será que endereço não deveria ter uma independência? Como é feita a relação entre as duas estruturas? Se for persistir como a relação é gerenciada?

Não sei o que é esse `Empresa`. O que está escrito na pergunta não me diz nada. Ou diz, que não faz sentido. Quem cria tem que justificar porque criou. Nunca crie algo que não saiba justificar muito bem. Mas depois dos comentários vi que não faz sentido mesmo, por duas razões: a pessoa física não pode ser empresa e o modelo fica torto assim podendo até não ter uma empresa, provavelmente não entendeu para que serve herança. É o que eu falei na pergunta anterior: aprenda primeiro como usar as ferramentas antes de usá-la.

A falta de entendimento do que está fazendo fará você cometer vários erros em sequência, e poderá cometer a vida toda se não criar uma base. Neste caso você precisa criar um objeto que seja uma pessoa, e já tem um tipo que define isso, é `Pessoa`, não tem que inventar mais nada. Mesmo ela sendo abstrata, e já falei que deveria ser, você pode criar objetos concretos, através de suas derivadas, mas guardar em uma variável do tipo `Pessoa`, e assim já tem o que precisa. O objeto será único para aquela entidade e obviamente seguirá exclusivamente um dos dois modelos atuais existentes: `PessoaJuridica` ou `PessoaFisica`.

Não sei se o `tipo` deveria ser `string`, mas pode ser, precisaria de um aprofundamento maior.

Será que não falta alguns *setters*? Talvez não, mas aí será que não falta um ou mais métodos que permitem alterar os dados de forma consistente?

Veja [Tipo do campo CPF ou CNPJ no banco de dados VARCHAR ou INT?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101).

Nos comentários fala muito em empresas, empresa é só pessoa jurídica. Pode ser só uso do termo errado, mas como costumo dizer, se não souber sequer usar os nomes certos das cosias não saberá o que aquilo significa, qual o papel daquilo no modelo, aí o erro é iminente, procure por [ontologia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontologia) e [taxinomia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomia_(geral)), pode ajudar modelar melhor se estudar mais profundamente.

Esta parte ainda é fácil, as pessoas erram no que vem depois. E estou curioso para ver esse depois, os comentários indicam boa coisa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Pegando algumas das informações dos comentários, ficou um pouco mais claro as necessidades da sua modelagem.

Eu entendo que seria interessante existir estas classes:

- PessoaFisica
- PessoaJuridica
- Endereco
- Pessoa
- Empresa
- Contato

Com algumas observações que me orientaram na correção da sua modelagem:

- Toda empresa, regularmente constituída, é uma pessoa jurídica, mas nem toda pessoa jurídica é uma empresa.
- Pessoa Física pode ter uma Empresa, mas uma Pessoa Física não pode ser uma empresa.

Sendo assim

1. `Empresa` **herda** de `PessoaJuridica`.
2. `Pessoa` **tem** uma `Empresa`. Remova a herança entre Empresa e PessoaFisica.
3. `PessoaFisica` e `PessoaJuridica` herdam de Pessoa.
4. Moveria as informações de endereço da `Pessoa` para uma classe `Endereco`. Pessoa tem uma lista de `Endereco`.
5. `Pessoa` tem uma lista de `Contato`, como está atualmente.

Outra coisa, usaria o construtor das classes para receber as informações delas, e não `set`. Avalie se precisa de todos os `get` existente. Se sim, pode mantê-los.

Sobre o campo `tipo` e o que explicou nos comentários, ele parece pertencer a uma classe `Profissional` que **herda** de `PessoaFisica` e, no caso de empresa, creio que a informação pertença ao `Ramo` (de atividade) da `Empresa`, na qual a `Empresa` **tem** um `Ramo`. Você pode usar este `Ramo` para `PessoaFisica` e abrir mão do `Profissional`, mas precisaria conhecer melhor o contexto para escolher. Mas deixo as duas opções.

Por fim, como disse nos comentários, creio que você pode optar por não usar herança alguma neste modelo e usar apenas composição. Mas na minha resposta eu preferi seguir o raciocínio de herança para não fugir muito do que já tinha. Lembre-se que não existe uma resposta certa e definitiva para este problema, pois as possíveis soluções são várias.

> Sou da época da programação estruturada e agora estou retornando e tentando me adequar com a OOP. Fiz um diagrama abaixo, poderiam analisar se estou no caminho certo?

Só uma observação sobre este afirmação. Muito se escuta sobre OOP ser a evolução da programação estruturada, mas tudo depende do problema que irá resolver. É verdade que antigamente os códigos macarrônicos eram comuns e o OOP foi vendido como a salvação, mas é possível manter um código não-OOP bem organizado. Aliás, em anos de profissão, é o que mais vi até hoje.

De fato, aplicar OOP em uma aplicação é bem complicado e normalmente é recomendado para casos onde a regra de negócio é bem complicada, no qual comumente o DDD (*Domain Driven Design*) aparece para dar uma certa organização a estas classes todas que podem se repetir em diferentes domínios de uma mesma aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

Um dos princípios que regem a orientação a objetos é que as classes possuam características e tenham comportamentos que sejam inerentes a elas e traduzam o que elas representam.

Na sua classe **Pessoa** você colocou atributos como bairro, cep, cidade e estado que não são características de uma pessoa mas sim do endereço associado a ela. Ainda, pelo que entendi, o que você usou como atributo nomeado endereço, seria o logradouro+número. Estes, junto aos outros atributos anteriormente citados estão associados ao conjunto que caracteriza o endereço de uma pessoa. Seria a mesma linha de raciocínio que você utilizou para criar uma classe Contato com os atributos inerentes à ela.

Aconselho que coloque **endereço** como sendo uma classe e traga todos os dados referentes a endereço para serem atributos dessa nova classe **Endereco**. Faça então uma relação entre Pessoa e Endereco assim como você fez com Contato.

Fazendo essas alterações acredito que seu modelo traduzirá num código extensível de maneira mais correta e permitirá o reuso de forma mais eficiente.

Comment: E por quais motivos deveriam seguir este conselho? Quais são as vantagens e benefícios? Quais os problemas com a estruturação atual que beneficia esta alteração? Poderia descrever isso na sua resposta?

Comment: Anderson, realmente minha resposta estava muito solta. Obrigada pelo feedback. Adicionei informações referentes aos princípios da orientação a objetos.