# TDD com micro serviços

Tags: tdd

Tenho dois micro serviços um depende do outro, o micro serviço B depende do A. Escrevi testes para o A e para o B. O teste do A roda sem depender de nenhum outro projeto, porém os Testes do B precisa de algumas ações que somente o A pode fazer. Por exemplo:

O A insere **Usuario** e o B faz a matricula de um **Usuario**. Então sera necessário existir um **Usuario** na base para realizar uma matricula. Ate o momento coloquei um script de insert no serviço B para inserir **Usuario**, ou seja, o script simula as ações que o A faria, quando rodo os teste do B ele chama o script que *simula o serviço A*, assim posso rodar os teste do B sem o serviço A. Porém não sei se isso é uma boa prática, alguém ja passou por essa situação?

Comment: É mais ou menos isso, um dos motivos de eu não usar as duas coisas, muita complexidade adicionada para pouco benefício. Tem o lado bom, fica na moda.

Comment: Mas qual a solução vc utiliza?

Comment: Uma simples, que não envolva complicar seu código, sua arquitetura para ficar na moda. Você precisa dessas cosias? Quase ninguém precisa. Mas falam tanto que as pessoas se sentem na obrigação de usar. Quase ninguém precisa. TDD feito errado, e quase todo mundo faz, é só desvantagem, MS em faz pouco sentido, porque ou você tem várias aplicações micro naturalmente e nem precisa pensar muito no que fazer, ou o MS adiciona muita complexidade para pouco ou nenhum benefício. O que alias seu enorme time deve saber como lidar com isso. Não trabalha em um time assim? Não faz sentido usar essas coisas.

Comment: Olá Bruno! Não entendi bem como o TDD entra neste cenário seu. Que tipo de teste você está fazendo: unitário, integração, outro? Os testes dependem do outro micro serviço no ar??

Comment: @Maniero posso dar um feedback? Vi você em outros comentários e respostas "desabafando" um pouco sobre estes e outros assuntos. Quase sempre concordo contigo, mas acho que isto acaba desviando do propósito da pergunta e confundindo os usuários. Espero que leve na boa o feedback :), depois removo aqui o comentário

Comment: @Dherik sim, tranquilo, mas o que acha que devo fazer, só ficar quieto, como todo mundo faz, e deixar a pessoa se estrepar?

Comment: @Dherik, estou fazendo teste de web service, ou seja, estou consumindo as url´s do serviço B. Porém, para utilizar o serviço B, preciso de Usuarios cadastrados na base, esses Usuarios são cadastrados com o serviço A.

Comment: @Maniero, o aviso pode continuar, creio que só a forma poderia mudar. Uma dica seria iniciar a resposta/comentário respondendo ao autor e, ao final, acrescentando o aviso com os detalhes necessários (já que deseja dar este recado), de preferência conhecendo o contexto dela: ela iniciou o projeto agora ou não? Ainda dá tempo de mudar?. Muitos usuários chegam a pergunta com o mesmo problema e querem ver a solução primeiro. Por exemplo, imagine que para toda dificuldade com React a primeira resposta comece falando para refletir seu uso e pensar em usar apenas JS puro?

Comment: @Dherik mas eu não respondi nada, eu questionei em comentário. Se eu quisesse responder eu teria postado uma resposta, por isso eu só comentei, para isto serve os comentários.

Comment: @Maniero, mas até no comentário creio que isto crie alguma confusão. Mas tenho um exemplo de resposta também, em um tópico de um usuário perguntando se o UML dele de classes estava correto. Ele comenta que estava querendo sair da forma procedural de código e pensar em OOP. Link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/311979/4492

Comment: @Dherik e qual é sua proposta? E qual o problema na pergunta?

Comment: @Maniero, eu comentei no meu comentário anterior a sugestão, mas tomei a liberdade de responder a pergunta do link citado anteriormente para demonstrar o que queria dizer :).

Comment: @Dherik é que a sua proposta só faz sentido se for uma resposta, eu só comentei. Depois vejo sua resposta. Geralmente eu vou lendo e respondendo a pergunta frase por frase, se a pessoa coloca no começo algo que eu acho que eu deva falar sobre, eu respondo isso no começo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente não há uma bala de prata para resolver este tipo de problema em testes.

Sua solução funciona mas é muito intrusiva a **A**, pois para testar o micro serviço **B** você precisa conhecer até o banco de dados do micro serviço **A** e inserir informações diretamente nele. Não me parece certo isto se os micro serviços são, por definição, independentes.

Basicamente, o melhor cenário possível para você seria iniciar o micro serviço **B** e não se preocupar em iniciar o micro serviço **A** (ou C, D, E... ). Ás vezes é possível, outras não. Tudo depende do ambiente que você tem disponível.

Normalmente, estas são as opções:

- Conectar o micro serviço **B** em uma instância do Wiremock que imita todas as respostas do micro serviço **A**. Você pode iniciar o Wiremock para isto separado de qualquer micro serviço.
- No micro serviço **B**, você pode customizar uma implementação *Fake* do código que chama o micro serviço **A**, incluindo algumas regras básicas, exemplo: "Se o CPF for X, eu retorno o UsuarioX". Assim, você pode iniciar o micro serviço **B** usando um determinado parâmetro que liga/desliga este "mock" dos serviços que chamam **A**.
- Conectar o micro serviço **B** em um ambiente compartilhado de instâncias onde teremos o micro serviço **A** (ou C, D...). Assim, você pode usar os usuários já existentes neste ambiente para fazer seus testes.

Dependendo de como seu micro serviço **A** funciona e dispõe suas funcionalidades, você também pode:

- Chamar a API do micro serviço **A** para criar os usuários que precisa antes de iniciar os testes no micro serviço **B**. Esta alternativa é mais confiável do que usar um script de banco de dados direto em **A**. Já vi testes automatizados desta maneira em ambientes com todos os micro serviços no ar, mas só funciona bem se há uma API disponível para tudo o que precisa ser feito.

Comment: "Chamar a API do micro serviço A para criar os usuários que precisa antes de iniciar os testes no micro serviço B", essa situação me parece a mais favorável. Posso ate colocar esse tipo de informação da documentação para rodar os testes.

Answer (score 2):

A melhor prática depende do tipo do teste, mas deve-se ter em mente que o mock é a resposta de muitos problemas.

Você tem o microserviço **A** e o microserviço **B**. Como **B** utiliza **A**, você cria um microserviço **Am**, que é o mock do serviço **A**. Ele tem a mesma API do serviço A e talvez uma API extra para ser configurado, mas a sua implementação é apenas um mock.

Os testes de unidade usarão apenas classes isoladas do módulo que estiver sendo testado e a maioria dos dependentes é mockada (mockar tudo cegamente pode ser ruim, como explico [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/273527/132), é necessário saber dosar).

Já em testes de aceitação ou de integração do microserviço **B**, convém subir, além do serviço **B**, o serviço **Am**. Assim quando o serviço **B** for integrar com o **A**, quem vai estar respondendo na verdade será o **Am**.

Um exemplo, levando-se em conta o seu caso concreto, seria algo mais ou menos assim:

- O serviço **A** oferece a APIs `cadastrarUsuario` e `login`.
- `cadastrarUsuario` recebe o nome do usuário e a senha e devolve um token ou um erro.
- `login` recebe o o nome do usuário e a senha e devolve verdadeiro ou falso.
- O serviço **Am** tem a mesma API que o serviço **A**.
- O serviço **A** mantém tudo em um banco de dados com persistência a longo prazo e pode se conectar com outros serviços internamente. O serviço **Am** mantém tudo na memória enquanto estiver rodando, não se conecta a mais nada e perde todos os seus dados assim que for desligado.
- O serviço **B** é responsável por realizar matrículas de usuários.
- Os testes do serviço **B** que necessitem do serviço **B** inteiro em execução, sobem também o serviço **Am**.

Note que a única coisa que é necessária para isso funcionar é que **A** e **Am** devam ter a mesma API. Entretanto, por vezes (nem sempre) pode ser útil que você faça com que **A** e **Am** tenham na maior extensão possível, o mesmo código, trocando-se apenas um componente interno para acessar o banco de dados.

Em especial, o mock é muito importante quando você vai integrar com um serviço externo (imagine que o serviço **A** seja uma API disponibilizada por terceiros para a qual você não tem qualquer controle ou conhecimento sobre a implementação). Nesse caso, é muito importante você construir um serviço **Am** para poder construir e testar o seu serviço **B**.

Por fim, existem cenários onde você vai precisar fazer testes de integração com os serviços **B** e **A**, sem mocks. O ideal é evitá-los ao máximo e minimizá-los sempre que possível, mas podem existir situações na qual evitar isso pode ser difícil, custoso ou inviável.